# LocalStorage is cropping output image

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

This is my first my first time. I Need Help!
I saved a certain image size to localStorage and when I want to get it back it was cropped. How can I stop the cropping? I have tried to use CSS `object-fit:cover`, `object-fit:contain`, it didn't work.

Here are my code:

image I save to localStorage:

```
li img {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
      }
      img {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
      }
<li><img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zestarla/image/upload/v1631394114/Trial/IMG_4976_tm7n8t.jpg"
              class="img"
              id="image47"
            /></li>
```

The javascript function:

```
var imageTouch = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("img"));
      imageTouch.forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("touchStart", onlyTouch, false);
      });

      function onlyTouch(ev) {
        //console.log("Here a touchstart event is triggered");
        ev.preventDefault();
        TouchFun();
      }

      imageTouch.forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", onlyClick, false);
      });

      function onlyClick(ev) {
        //console.log("Here a click event is triggered");
        ev.preventDefault();
        TouchFun();
      }

      function TouchFun() {
        if (confirm("Do You want to save this image?")) {
          var target = event.target;
          imageSel = target.src;
          var myNewElement = document.createElement("img");
          myNewElement.src = imageSel;
          myNewElement.setAttribute("id", "selectedImage");
          myNewElement.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
          myNewElement.setAttribute("width", "200px");
          myNewElement.setAttribute("height", "200px");
          //console.log(myNewElement);
          //var baseImage = getBase64Image(myNewElement.src);
          localStorage.setItem("image", getBase64Image(myNewElement));
          //console.log(baseImage);
        } else {
          console.log("cancel");
        }
      }
      

      function getBase64Image(img) {
        // Create an empty canvas element
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // Copy the image contents to the canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(jpg);base64,/, "");
      }
```

JavaScript function to view the image:

```
        const recentImageDataUrl = localStorage.getItem("image");
        if (recentImageDataUrl) {
          document
            .querySelector("#imageSaved")
            .setAttribute("src", recentImageDataUrl);
        }
      });
```

HTML code to view the image:

```
#imageArea img {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: none;
      }
 <div
            id="imageArea"
            class="col-sm-8 col-ls-10 col-md-9 col-xl-10 align-items-end"
          >
            <img src="" id="imageSaved" style="width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;background-size: cover;"/>
          </div>
```

Please What am I doing wrong? this image should not be cropped

Comment: Reduce your problem: if the problem is localStorage, then what you save should not be what you get out: you can verify that immediately by doing a `getItem` after `setItem` and verifying that the content's the same. If it is: this has nothing to do with localStorage and you can complete ignore everything that precedes you getting the data out of localStorage.

Comment: i dont know what you are trying as your post says localStorage is cropping this is nowere close to what you are describing

Comment: try to someup your problem and and show what you wanted to achive with hand made examples either by screen shots drawing on paint in windows or some other way possible

Answer (score 0):

I just remove this lines and it work fine.

```
 myNewElement.setAttribute("width", "200px");
 myNewElement.setAttribute("height", "200px");
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem with just a few more minutes of testing, you asked it too early and you should probably delete it again. Stackoveflow is for questions you can't answer yourself, and that's clearly not the case here.